# How to replace symbols with indexed variables?

Tags: sympy

```html
import sympy as s
H0,z,g=s.symbols('H0 z g')
def f(H0,g,z):
    H1=(6/H0)/(g+(6-g)*(1+z)**3)
    return H1
```

How to replace the symbols H0 and g in H1 with x[0] and x[1] ?
( Not by substitution, because my actual H1 is a big expression )

Comment: How about calling `f(x[0], x[1], z)`?

Comment: What are `x[0]` and `x[1]`? Can you please [edit] your question to clarify what you want to achieve. Preferably, give us an example code and a desired outcome or tell us what doesn’t work. Please also read [mcve].

Comment: I want to optimize H1.  I am getting error TypeError: f() missing 1 required positional argument: 'g'    . so i am trying to define my function in one variable

Answer (score 0):

If you want `f` to have one parameter, how about:

```
def f(x):
    H0, g, z = x
    H1=(6/H0)/(g+(6-g)*(1+z)**3)
    return H1
```

Or if you want x and z to be separate parameters then

```
def f(x, z):
    H0, g = x
    H1=(6/H0)/(g+(6-g)*(1+z)**3)
    return H1
```